# Find the area of the part of plane $ z = y + 1$ which is inside cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, $z$ is free

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

What I have tried so far :

$$ S = \int\int \sqrt{(0)^2 + (1)^2 + 1} dA$$ Converting to spherical coordinates:
$$ \int_{0}^{4\pi}\int_{0}^{4} \sqrt{2} \space r \space drd\theta = \int_{0}^{4\pi} \frac{r^2}{2} f4 \space 0 = \int_{0}^{4\pi} 8 \space  d\theta  $$ 
Fairly sure this is incorrect as I dont know where my theta has run off to. What did I do wrong in the integration ?

Comment: I can't understand the use of spherical coordinates. Use polar or cartesian to find the area of  the unit disk $=\pi $. Therefore $\int \int _R\sqrt{2}dA=\sqrt{2}\int \int _R \, dA=\pi  \sqrt{2}$

Comment: what are the bounds for double integral R dA ?

Comment: using polar coordinates, $\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^1rdrd\theta $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plane would cut the cylinder at 45 degree, thus making an ellipse, making the radius of longer side $\sqrt2$. Since along x axis there is no such constraint, the radius of ellipse remains 1 in that direction.
Area of ellipse = $\pi*a*b$ = $\pi*\sqrt2*1$ = $\sqrt2\pi$

\begin{align}
Ans = \bbox[yellow,5px,border:2px solid red]{\sqrt2\pi}
\end{align}